# Long running programs redirected file output

Tags: bash, io-redirection

To help in my  mathematics research I wrote a Python2 program 
and in bash invoked it as

```
python myprog.py > myoutput.txt
```

First I ran it for a small set of input values and got the output in fraction of a second.

Now for a larger input data (so the output should contain previous run's output as subset) it has been running for hours.
In another terminal window I find that "myoutput.txt" is created at the time of invocation but is empty. Is there a temporary location where the output is stored that I can peep into?

My program has a for loop and should output one line for every iteration of that loop. When the range was  1 to 35 I  got 35 lines of output immediately. When I increased the range as 1 to 175 nearly a day has gone by and no output.
Anyone can help?

Comment: If you would like to monitor the writing to your file, perhaps try the tee command.

Comment: That won't help. Output is buffered by default when writing to a file or pipe, so `tee` won't show anything until the buffer is flushed.

Answer (score 0):

bad practice - the redirect will perform the write only in the end of the program.

use logging module. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html

- edit: 
  Write is done not at the end but when the buffer exhausted.thanks barmar

Comment: Learning it the hard way. Thanks. I did not want to terminate the program forcefully lest I should lose the partial results obtained. Looks like there is no way.

Comment: Not just at the end of the program, whenever the output buffer fills up. But it's probably something like 4K characters.

Comment: At the end of the program, or when the output buffer gets full, or when the program flushes the output explicitly (which obviously the user's code isn't doing).